# Is there a function that triggers when there is change with the value of a cell with formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, formula, auto

I have a formula "=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(MAX(if(I2:P2<=TODAY(),I2:P2))))" in column C, Now I am looking for google app script which can trigger and clear the contents of other columns when a date in the column C changes with the effect of the formula that has been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

No events get triggered when a formula result changes. But since the formula result only changes when its parameters change, you can detect a change in one of those *parameter ranges* with an `onEdit()` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) or [installable on change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), and then do whatever needs doing.

The formula you quote can probably be simplified like this:

`=min(today(), max(I2:P2))`

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.